# C# How to know if a given path represents a root drive?

Tags: c#, directory, root, drive

How can I know if a given directory is a root drive?

(aside from checking if its path equals to "A:", "B:", "C:", etc.)

Comment: You're wanting to know if the given directory is the root directory of some partition, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I asked for.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Check if DirectoryInfo.Parent is null or not

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo("");
if(d.Parent == null) { IsRoot = true; }
```

you can also get the root by using DirectoryInfo.Root;

Answer (score 11):

Try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getpathroot.aspx):

```
if (Path.GetPathRoot(location) == location) {...}
```

Comment: he already has the path, he wants to see if it's the root, not get the root.

Comment: @Titan: If getting the root returns the same string, then it's a root.  It may not be the best approach, but it is valid.

Comment: @Ben thats true but it's far less efficient. It not only requires working with 2 strings but comparing them too.

Comment: @DustinDavis far less efficient then what? if you allocate a `DirectoryInfo` you now have to GC a `DirectoryInfo` instead of a string,  `GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint` uses interop and will also have overhead, `Directory.GetLogicalDrives()` returns a string array...

Answer (score 5):

It's much more complicated than checking the Parent property.

[Determining Whether a Directory Is a Mounted Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363940.aspx)

One approach would be to see if [`GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364994.aspx) succeeds.

Of course that won't work for network path, determining if a network drive represents the root directory of a partition may not be possible remotely.

Comment: My program is in C# and GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint is a native C function. Anyway DirectoryInfo.Parent seems to work perfectly. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: It works perfectly unless you ask it about a mount point.  In which case `DirectoryInfo.Parent` will tell you it is a subdirectory when in fact it is the root directory of another partition.  There is no managed function to test whether a particular directory is the root of its partition, which is why I suggested a native Win32 function.

Answer (score 3):

Also Here's another way I found:

```
 public static bool IsLogicalDrive(string path)
 {
     return (new DirectoryInfo(path).FullName == new DirectoryInfo(path).Root.FullName);
 }
```

if this function returns true, then it means that given path represents a root drive!

Comment: Is it necessary to create 2 objects?   How about "return path == Path.GetPathRoot(path)"

Comment: @DarrelLee, while I agree that `Path.GetPathRoot()` can be the more convenient option in some cases, it does not find the root of relative paths. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getpathroot?view=netframework-4.7 Also, since we're using a string comparison we'll want to make sure both sides get the same formatting.

Comment: On that note, even `new DirectoryInfo(path).Root.FullName` isn't sure to be consistent because it could return an upper or lower case version of the drive letter. Better do a string conversion as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way I found:

```
public static bool IsLogicalDrive(string path)
{
    return Directory.GetLogicalDrives().Contains(path);
}
```

This one actually checks if the given path represents one of the current system's logical drives.

Comment: Not all partitions have their own drive letter.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938934.aspx

Comment: `Directory.GetLogicalDrives` returns a `string[]`. `System.Array` implements `System.Collections.IList`, but it provides an explicit interface implementation for Contains: ((.NET 3.5+: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336401(v=vs.110).aspx )) ((.NET 2, 3: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.array.system.collections.ilist.contains(v=vs.85).aspx )) ((.NET 1.1: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa310885(v=vs.71).aspx )) The array must be cast to an `IList` before calling Contains.