# Save and restore values from ArrayList

Tags: c#, store

I store some string values in an array list at runtime. When the application closes I want to store the data from the array list in another location so that I can open and retrieve the data the next time the application starts. What are some possible ways to do this?

Comment: You really shouldn't ever use `ArrayList` anymore.  You should use `List<T>` so that you have a strongly typed collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Reading` and `Writing` from/to files or storing the values in windows registry. 
For Reading/Writing from/to files use:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:/store.dll"); //for reading
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:/store.dll"); //for writing
```

This is the basic. Here are two great articles for this:

1. [Reding from files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b)
2. [Writing to files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k)

I used this for storing the High Scores for a simple game. :)

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/189670/Accessing-Windows-Registry-in-C-net) is a nice tutorial for using Windows registry.

Comment: Why `.dll`? Dll is for libraries, and not for data.

Comment: Just an example. It can be any type of file... :D

Comment: Is there any different, more "isolate" way, to save and restore my data? I prefer no to use window registry

Comment: You can create a hidden file. :) Is this better?

Comment: If i haven't a D disk partition it stored somewhere else, or it doesn't stored? How can i know what drive letters has every pc? :-)

Comment: This can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047570/c-sharp-how-to-know-if-a-given-path-represents-a-root-drive :D

Answer (score 0):

You could `Serialize` the ArrayList and write it to disk, then later on load the file and `Deserialize` it to an object:

```
    public static XDocument Serialize<T>(T objectIn, Type[] extraTypes)
    {
        try
        {
            var target = new XDocument();
            XmlSerializer s = extraTypes != null ? new XmlSerializer(objectIn.GetType(), extraTypes) : new XmlSerializer(objectIn.GetType());
            s = extraTypes != null
                ? new XmlSerializer(objectIn.GetType(), extraTypes)
                : new XmlSerializer(objectIn.GetType());

            var writer = target.CreateWriter();

            s.Serialize(writer, objectIn);

            writer.Close();
            return target;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not serialize object: {0}", ex.Message));
        }
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(XDocument xDocument, string defaultNamespace)
    {
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), defaultNamespace);

        T result = (T)s.Deserialize(xDocument.CreateReader());

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: How can i call this method? I suppose T objectIn is my arraylist, what is the Type[] extraTypes